# Remove Points from GeoJSON

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson

When using the OSM Overpass API I'm getting back JSONs with all the points, which destroy my geometry when converting into GMT file format.

How can I remove the Points from a GeoJSON while retaining the Features with "type": "LineString"?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/hFGb5iuT) is my complete GeoJSON (Pastebin). Features like this should go:

```
{
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      6.6807119,
      58.2607599
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "id": 3738725904,
  "properties": {

  },
  "type": "Feature"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only keep LineString features:

JS (ES6):

```
data.features.filter(feature => feature.geometry.type === 'LineString')
```

jq:

```
cat data.geojson | jq -c '.features[] | select(.geometry.type == "LineString")'
```

Comment: Is this JS? I need a Linux commandline tool. Would it run with NodeJS?

Comment: Yes it would. You could also use something like `jq` but I find nodejs to be easier to read and use